# Problema ao incluir arquivo JS em projeto com VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2, vue-router

Estou com o seguinte problema: Ao incluir um arquivo local .js em meu projeto com VueJS recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem minha estrutura e código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebi que se incluir um arquivo externo, via CDN por exemplo, funciona perfeitamente. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Simples cara, percebeu que o script está sendo chamado depois da tag **body**. Correto seria:

```
<body><script src="/../rocketstore/dist/js/mais.min.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: Entendi, eu ja tinha tentando passar dentro da body, sem sucesso. Ficaria deste mesmo jeito que vc pontuou:

<body>
    <script src="/../rocketstore/dist/js/main.min.js"></script>
  </body>

Comment: Estranho, vc já tinha colocado dentro da tag body e mesmo assim não funcionou. Faz o seguinte o caminho aí tbm está errado. Vc já está na raiz do projeto, não precisa chamar **/../rocketstore**. Põe dist/js/main.min.js que vai funcionar.

Comment: É o caminho esta realmente errado, hehe. É q eu tava tentando de todo jeito. Corrigi o caminho e mesmo assim não funcionou. Creio que seja algum problema com o vue-router com o o webpack. Por que quando eu clico no caminho do script no source code, ele direciona para: http://localhost:8080/dist/js/main.min.js#/ e ao invés de carregar o script, carrega o html da view padrão.

Comment: Entendi, se o link já está sendo direcionado, o arquivo já está sendo executado. Tem que ver aí mesmo como está o roteamento aí no projeto.

Comment: Obrigado pela disponibilidade amigo.

Comment: Blza man, faça uma nova pergunta, colocando os scripts para obter ajuda com este problema com o router.